# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans

I am a newbie to ror and I just installed NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 and all the required software's on my terminal server and all seem to work well, only when one user is running it. Problem is when an another user runs, netbeans is fetching the same port number (3000) all the time and errors out with the message

> C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `initialize': Only one
>   usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
>   normally permitted. - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

(Guess NetBeans is supposed to fetch these port numbers automatically)

This seem to be working fine in other terminal servers.

Is it got do something with my ruby code or an issue with the netbeans.

Any help please..

Comment: I don't know NetBeans, but you can run Rails on a different port with `rails s -p <port>`

Answer (score 1):

You can run rails server with specified port by console instead of NetBeans IDE. I think NetBeans also can set ports, but I didn't used this IDE for long time and forgot it....

In your project folder first.

If you are using Rails 2.*

```
> ruby script/server -p 3001
```

If you are using Rails 3+

```
> rails s -p 3001
```

-p XXXX is the port you will use, you can specify a port that is different with another user's.

Hope it helps.